# Software for creating lighting plans/diagrams?

Tags: lighting, software

I'd like to share lighting plans with my crew -- what software exists for creating lighting plans?  What are the pros/cons to the different packages?

I've been using Microsoft Visio, but there must be a better app for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sylights (free registration required): http://www.sylights.com/

OLDC (free, with donation requirements for commercial use): http://www.lightingdiagrams.com/

Photo Diagrams (free, Flash-based): http://www.professionalsnapshots.com/PhotoDiagram/

Strobox (iPhone app, free): http://app.strobox.com/

Answer (score 9):

There's an online creator at http://www.lightingdiagrams.com

Comment: Nice, I'm tired of using PowerPoint :)

Comment: Too much fun! http://bit.ly/aSulAj

Comment: It even works on iPad's! This app is great!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good free lighting diagrams software :

http://rienquepourlesyeux.free.fr/Lighting%20Studio%20Photo/studio%20lighting.htm

You can create, print, save, export in JPG your lighting diagrams with settings for all elements.

it is for information.

Answer (score 1):

[www.lightingdiagram.com](http://www.lightingdiagram.com) has an online creator.

Comment: Can you describe the pros and cons of this software?

Comment: This is a different site than lightingdiagrams.com. They seem to have more backgrounds, lights and so forth than lightingdiagram without-the-s.com

Answer (score 1):

lightingdiagrams.com also offer a free-for-personal-use download of a [PSD](http://www.lightingdiagrams.com/Downloads/Lighting-Diagram-Sheet-G-1.x-for-Photoshop) for photoshop which contains elements like you see below.  These are each on separate layers so you can easily arrange them.  There is also a version for PS Elements.  A good option if you have photoshop and want to work offline or add your own elements.

[image: lightingdiagrams.com]