# Is there a 3D lighting diagram tool?

Tags: software, lighting

I have tried a few tools for creating lighting diagrams. There is a good list on [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/641/software-for-creating-lighting-plans-diagrams).

While these tools are pretty good, they only provide a "top view" of the scene, so vertical distances of objects from the floor can only be entered as notes. Also, representing two elements one above the other is kind of messy.

Short of building a scene in a 3D application like Blender or Maya, are there any simple 3D lighting diagram tools that can output top and side views for a given scene, or better yet, a perspective view from any place in the scene?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What software can I use for 3D lighting simulation?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10447/what-software-can-i-use-for-3d-lighting-simulation)

Comment: So you are looking for the exact same thing that is mentioned in the duplicate thread, just easier?

Comment: @mattdm: I was asking about 3D diagrams, not 3D lighting simulation which is also very interesting but for a different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to view actual simulations of lighting, then [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) might be the right product for you. I haven't used it for lighting diagrams specifically, but by and large it's a pretty easy 3D modelling tool.

Comment: Good suggestion. Models for studio photography aren't in abundance at the Google 3D warehouse, but there are some. Thanks!